# do prebuilt java classes get updated?

Tags: java

I opened up a project in which I was using the DecimalFormat class.
I remember the project compiling correctly and this is how I was using the DecimalFormat class:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Receipt {
public static void main(String[] args) {
float price = 0;
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
  System.out.println("please enter a price");
  price = scanner.nextFloat();
  System.out.println(df.format(price);
     }

  }
```

This worked correctly but now I get the following error

```
The method format(Object, StringBuffer, FieldPosition) in the type DecimalFormat is not applicable for the arguments (float)
```

In the past the format method just consisted of one parameter but now it consists of 3.

Could this be a case where the package gets updated and old methods/parameters are changed?

Comment: Posted code would not compile. Also you probably wrote another class named `DecimalFormat` in your current package. Don't do that.

Comment: Last week that exact code was working, and I do not have another class named that

Comment: That's not your actual code, as there's a missing parenthesis, and you can't assign a literal double to a float.

Comment: However calling DecimalFormat.format(double) with a float parameter should be fine.

Comment: updated my code to include more of what is going on 
last week i ran this code it worked and now im getting the error as described in the post

Comment: Your code compiles for me with both Java 8 and Java 16.  (After fixing the typo!)   Go to the command prompt and try it for yourself.   Maybe this is just another example of an IDE behaving strangely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do prebuilt java classes get updated?

Yes.  They do.

However, Oracle goes to great lengths to try to avoid breaking backwards compatibility.  They wouldn't remove a (public) method without first deprecating it.  And they haven't done that in this case.

The `DecimalFormat` class has never had a `format` method with one `float` argument.  You can confirm this by looking at the javadocs for current and old versions of Java.  (For example [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).)

However, there is a `format` method that takes a `double` argument ... declared in the superclass `NumberFormat`.

---

**UPDATE** - I cannot reproduce your problem using `javac` from the command prompt (Java 8 or Java 16).  I suspect your actual problem is that your IDE is "confused".